# How big a performance difference will byte have over int?

Tags: java, performance, integer, byte

I'm coding a traffic simulation in Java, and used int for most of my variables, including loop counters and data arrays. The final data read in should be about 50 "agents" and 50 "nodes", where each agent has about 5 characteristics and the node graph will be updated along with the clock to reflect the average speed a car can travel along the road.

My question is whether I should switch from using int to byte types for variables that can fit in the -127 to 127 range. Will this have a significant improvement in performance in the end? If not, at what point (i.e. number of variables in question or calculations per second) will the performance increase be noticeable?

Comment: We have no idea what the bottlenecks in your code are - but you should be able to determine this through testing. Have you already set performance goals, and written benchmarks to check whether or not you've met them? What were the results?

Comment: AFAIK , using int is better because introducing bytes will cause extra effort and thus less performance , whether 'int' are more natually and casually available

Comment: If you are not asking from a theoretical point but a practical one I would say: Don't worry about that. This issue won't be the bottleneck.

Comment: I know this is a Java question, but in C you can determine if `int` is faster than or equally fast as a byte by doing `sizeof(uint8_t) == sizeof(uint_fast8_t)` or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will this have a significant improvement in performance in the end? If not, at what point (i.e. number of variables in question or calculations per second) will the performance increase be noticeable?

It won't increase performance.  In fact, I'd expect calculations to be *slower* if you use `byte` instead of `int`.  A typical native instruction set doesn't support byte-wise arithmetic.  Instead it will be implemented using 32 bit instructions, and extra instructions will be needed to convert between 8 and 32 bit quantities.

The only situation where I would expect you to see a performance improvement would be if you were doing large-scale operations on arrays of numbers.  That's due to the fact that a large array of bytes occupied 1/4 the memory of a large array of ints (with the same length).  Since the limiting factor for large-scale  is memory bandwidth, you will see a performance improvement.  (There will also be secondary performance benefits, due to the effect of reducing memory demand on the GC and on the virtual memory system.)

Note that you do not get this for individual `byte` fields or local variables, because the JVM aligns these on word boundaries.

Answer (score 2):

No, you should not at all. `int`s are generally much faster due to the architecture of your processor. When calculating with `byte`s, your CPU is internally converting everything to bytes and back.

Answer (score 0):

On most modern 32-bit or 64-bit systems, playing with anything different from the system's native int size will have an impact on performance since you'll have to zero/sign extend the smaller variable to the register size, or mask out the extended bits to limit the value to the type's range.

But in some cases if your program accesses memory very frequently in a big array then using a narrower type for the array may increase performance since the bottleneck is often I/O, and that also makes more elements fit in cache which reduce memory access greatly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Intel CPUs - Have you looked into using SSE instructions, where you might be able to manipulate 16 x 8 bit bytes at the same time. I believe that SSE parameters are available via Java but have not tried it.

Comment: Based on the OP's description of the problem, I think it is unlikely that those instructions are applicable.  Besides, if he is coding in Java, "he" wouldn't use those instructions.  It would be the native code compiler / optimizer that decides to use them.